# me aparece este error: 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read', como puedo solucionnarlo?

Tags: python, vscode, opencv

python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\facerec.cpp:61: error: (-2:Unspecified error) File can't be opened for reading! in function 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8r72.png

Comment: Parece que el problema es con la ruta. Al string 'C:\IA\reconocimiento...', ponle una r al principio asi: `r'C:\IA\reconocitomiento...'`

Comment: Bienvenida Fiorella Cassina, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas.